# Prove that a field/commutative ring is IBN (invariant basis number).

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I am searching all over and it keeps coming up how trivial it is, but I don't actually see the proof of a field being IBN. I would also like to know where a proof of a nonzero commutative ring is IBN can be found, because I keep finding in books that it is simply used as an example. I'm fine with receiving some bibliography.

Comment: For a field... are you aware of the fact that modules over a field are simply vector spaces? Then it is a standard theorem of linear algebra

Comment: Yup... this appears (essentially) in every linear algebra book.

Comment: @user264745 The IBN property is usually defined as the well-definedness of rank for *finite-dimensional* free  modules. And then it's a theorem that well-definedness of rank for arbitrary free modules follows. See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) for instance. So there's no need to think about infinite dimensional vector spaces when verifying that fields have the IBN property.

Comment: @AlexKruckman My bad I thought it was same thing as invariant dimension property. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @user264745 I think it _is_ the same as what you called "invariant dimension property" for division rings, just nobody calls it that.  The reason nobody mentions the infinite case is because it is (counterintuitively, maybe) not interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for a field, just note that modules over a field are vector spaces so this is a standard theorem in Linear Algebra.

For general commutative rings see for example exercise 11, chapter 2 in Atiyah-Macdonald's "Introduction to commutative algebra" (here it is used tensor product, but the result can be proved also without using it).